# Using commas to separate large numbers in Django FloatField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm setting up an app with Django and I need to show large numbers (sometimes many billions) on my home page.

Right now I have set up my model with a classic:

```
required_number = models.FloatField()
```

Which yields me a number similar to 126645602100.0. 
Naturally I find this very hard to read, and it becomes really problematic to visually compare this number to another one which would be in the order of millions instead of billions.

Would there be a way to format this number in order to get something like 126,645,602,100 or even 126'645'602'100?

I'm thinking maybe FloatField is not adequate, or maybe the answer lies in my html treatment of this variable.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be global use then you can use [thousand_separator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/formatting/) in your settings.py:

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=True

THOUSAND_SEPARATOR=','

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR='.'

NUMBER_GROUPING=3
```

If you don't want to use it on certain data on template just add built in template tag [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 required_number= models.FloatField(localize=True)
```

and read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/formatting/

Comment: That's a very good solution and a great documentation. Thanks!